# Ubuntu is not installing on vaio with windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vaio, sony

I tried installing Ubuntu on Sony vaio 15126 with windows 8 preloaded in it. I was unable to install and could not boot from the dvd too. Could I get the steps to be followed. Thanks !

Comment: Please look through related questions on the site -- some probable answers.  Could be UEFI or BIOS issues here.  You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Hi Belacqua. It says File:\ubuntu\winboot\wnbildr.mbc
Status: 0xc000007b
Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here with another Vaio E series, model SVE1513G1EW. The firmware (InsydeH2O) doesn't offer a boot device selection menu for this model, which effectively locks you out of using dual boot with EFI. Even if you set the linux entry as the first boot device in the NVRAM when installing it, next time you manage to boot Windows 8 again it will place itself first, thus precluding you from booting into linux since there is no boot device selection menu to choose from.
It would be helpful if you could post a complaint to the Federal Trade Commission or a Consumer Protection agency in your area.

There are other people [reporting](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f320/sony-vaio-boot-menu-677459.html) this problem with the E series.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

the error message you got means you tried to install Ubuntu inside Windows (via the Wubi installer).
The problem is that Wubi is not compatible with GPT (preinstalled Windows8 are on GPT disks).

**Solution:**

Install Ubuntu the standard way, on its own partitions, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall